# Windows Startup Script works but has no interface

Tags: windows-server-2008, startup, task-scheduler

I have a .CMD startup script (Scheduled for startup via Task Scheduler). It invokes several executable files via DOS commands, like this:

```
start "Workflow Processor starting..." /D "C:\Sandbox\Publish\XR_Admin" "MyBigProcessingApp.exe" "..\..\config\MyCompany.wfc"
```

This seems to be working okay, ***except that I do not get any UI for my .EXE files.*** It is pretty important to have my .EXE UI's because sometimes we need to alter or modify them while they're running.

Currently I only see the .EXE stuff in my task manager, which tells me the script semi-worked.

But why would my .EXE UI's be non-existent? How can I make sure the .EXE's have their UI's displayed?

The startup script is run under the Domain Administrator account. Any ideas what is going on with the missing UI's on my executables?

Cheers,
Devtron

Answer (score 3):

You may want to do a logon script. Startup scripts are run by the system when it boots up. Logon scripts are run in userland when the user logs on.

Comment: This is almost definitely the issue.

Comment: But I need these services to run specifically at startup. Not logon. Is this possible? We may need to reboot these servers, "on the fly", and need these .EXE services to run when the computer reboots. Any ideas? These are production important .EXE files that process telemetry data from hardware. We cannot wait for someone to logon to each and every server, just to start these up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you execute your commands via a startup script from a GPO published to the system, you can launch your exe's from a batch file that you link into the GPO and it will display to the UI before the GINA displays. We do this for our startup scripts today and it works fine.

Comment: Cool. I originally set it up as a GPO but couldnt get it to work. I think this was due to my lack of physical restart. I dont think my GPO was going into effect because I was "restarting" not ever shutting down. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Restarting will kick off the system GPO. Just make sure you create a batch file for the startup script and launch that then call your exe's from there. You should see it process in when the machine starts up but prior to the GINA showing. Look in the event log if it doesn't seem to be running.